# python: How do I return value without bracket?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to figure out how to return a value without bracket. 
Assume I have following function below.

```
    def function(n):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        return a - b, a + b
    print function(n)
```

this prints out

```
    (-1, 3)
```

But I want this function to print out

```
    -1 3
```

Comment: Why? What's the problem with `(-1, 3)`?

Comment: my professor wants function to print out in this format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're returning a tuple from your function. So, receive it as two variables, then print each:

```
x, y = function(n)
print x, y
```

Or receive it as one variable, then print its items:

```
x = function(n)
print x[0], x[1]
```

Finally, since the return value is a sequence, you can join it, but you have to convert each item to a string first since they're integers:

```
print " ".join(map(str, function(x)))
```

If you are using Python 3, or using `from __future__ import print_function`, then `print` is a function, and you can use unpacking to turn your function's return value into multiple arguments:

```
print(*function(x))
```

Comment: And in Python 3, you can do `print(*(-1, 3))`. It's a nice feature to have.

Comment: Yeah, having `print` as a function is nice. I'll add a bit about that.